# To what extent can Office 365 Admins see their User's Data

Tags: onedrive, privacy, cloud, cloud-storage

I have been using an Office 365 Account (including it's services such as OneDrive, Outlook, OneNote and more) provided by an institution for over four years now. I'm wondering on how much access Admins of the institution have to my data. Are they able to just scroll through my Emails, open and download my OneDrive data or are there some sort of restrictions to what they can and can't access.

Comment: Yes. Admins can do all of that and place legal holds on your information and perform advanced searches through your data, even if you’ve deleted it. This shouldn’t be a surprise. How else do you expect organizations to follow regulations and enforce policies?

Answer (score 1):

> If you use a Microsoft product with an account provided by an
> organization you are affiliated with, such as your work or school
> account, that organization can:

> - Control and administer your
>   Microsoft product and product account, including controlling
>   privacy-related settings of the product or product account.
> - Access
>   and process your data, including the interaction data, diagnostic
>   data, and the contents of your communications and files associated
>   with your Microsoft product and product accounts.

> You should direct your privacy inquiries, including any requests to
> exercise your data protection rights, to your organization’s
> administrator.

Source: [Products provided by your organization—notice to end users](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement#mainnoticetoendusersmodule)